# How to catch this type of exceptions?

Tags: c#, .net, exception

I'm starting getting tired of this exception. Can't handle it, even so I'm using this:

`AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(CurrentDomain_UnhandledException);`

Still no success, Can anyone explain me, how I should handle it in a nice way. Or how to detect that it have fired this message and close the application, because I'm starting it automatically everytime it closes.

Btw, It's Console application.

[image]

Comment: Attach a debugger.  What kind of exception is this?  An access violation?  Out-of-memory?  Stack overflow?  Where is it happening (call stack)?  Are you hosting some component that is causing this exception?  I would try to find the reason behind it and fix it rather than try to suppress it by catching it.

Comment: It's not so easy to catch this, It fires random way. Like it works for a week or so and baaam, sometimes it fires right away.. Very hard to understand where the problem is, and can't run with attached debugger all the time...

Comment: When it happens though, if you have a debugger installed (like Visual Studio), you can attach it to the process and click "Cancel" on the dialog to start debugging to get more information about the exception.

Comment: Yes, It could be possible if application will be running on one machine.. It runs on ~ 150 machines.. (or maybe it's possible to install express visual studio just to catch this bastard :) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO best way solving this is to use [remote debugging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y7f5zaaa(v=VS.71).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried placing a `try{...} catch(Exception e){...}` block in your main, then posting all exception data to the Windows Event Viewer?
Or similarly checking the Windows Event information that is currently there.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/02/console-apps-and-appdomaincurrentdomainunhandledexception.html) and [here](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/02/improved-unhandled-exception-behavior-in-net-20.html) ´s are some good posts, why you get the Dialog even when you register the UnhandledExceptionEvent.

If you register to the event, it doesn´t prevent the application from beeing closed/exited. As far as i know it is by design. In the Event you have the option to log the exception and verify what went wrong in your application.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any P/Invoke calls at all? I have had issues in the past with C interop before, where the C dll was causing an access violation error internally, which in turn crashed the C# application catastrophically - much like your screenshot above. Unfortunately it turned into a case of hunting down the entry point (P/Invoke) into the C dll by trial and error, and then fixing the C code.

If you are using P/Invoke, are all the expected dependencies on the machines and the correct versions?